# Nodejs "querystring" module

Tags: node.js

I used built-in "querystring" module in my project.

Here is my sample code

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    travelDate: "19-Sep-2015",
    travelDate: "05-Nov-2015",
});

console.dir(postData);
```

But it logs `'travelDate=05-Nov-2015'`.

I expected to get the result `'travelDate=19-Sep-2015&travelDate=05-Nov-2015'`

Is there any method to solve the problem?

**Update : I illustrate my problem more details**

I know the query parameters key should be unique.But I need to fetch data from the website.I observe it's format of **Form Data**.

They have identical Keys("travelDate") showed below.

```
_eventId:showWtLblResult
mode:searchResultInter
wvm:WVMD
tripType:RT
origin:KHH
destination:NRT
travelDate:19-Sep-2015
travelDate:05-Nov-2015
adults:1
children:0
infants:0
cabinClass:ECONOMY
promoCode:
pointOfPurchase:OTHERS
flightNumberOW:
fareOW:
flightNumberRT:
fareRT:
channel:PB
bookingSource:
skyscanner_redirectid:
flexTrvlDates:
```

So I can't wrap my request body concisely.

I am a little stubborn that I hope to keep my code concise.

Comment: An object can't have two identical keys

Comment: In fact, in ES5 strict mode, duplicate keys on an object is actually a syntaxError.  In ES6, it is allowed, but the second will overwrite the first so the object will only have the second key/value.  Object keys must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using two identical keys in the same object; the second is overwriting the first here, which is why you're seeing the results you are.  You should instead use  this:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    travelDate01: "19-Sep-2015",
    travelDate02: "05-Nov-2015",
});

console.dir(postData);
```

Or something similar.

If, however, the querystring parameter names must be identical, [you can pass them as an array](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options)

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    travelDate: [
        "19-Sep-2015",
        "05-Nov-2015"
    ]
});
```

Comment: Of course. :) if any of the answers have helped, you should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and/or upvoting them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use two identical keys for query string, here is an example:

```
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    travelDate: [
        "19-Sep-2015",
        "05-Nov-2015"
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

query parameters key should be unique. Why do not you have something like this:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    travelStartDate: "19-Sep-2015",
    travelEndDate: "05-Nov-2015",
});

console.dir(postData);
```

Which yields the result like:

```
'travelStartDate=19-Sep-2015&travelEndDate=05-Nov-2015'
```